# Nested calls from inside a default WndProc

Tags: c, winapi

I have the following output from Spy++:

```
<00227> 001F1732 P WM_MOUSEMOVE fwKeys:MK_LBUTTON xPos:-43 yPos:28
<00228> 001F1732 S WM_SIZING fwSide:WMSZ_LEFT lprc:0012F410
<00229> 001F1732 R WM_SIZING fProcessed:False
<00230> 001F1732 S WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING lpwp:0012F404
<00231> 001F1732 S  WM_GETMINMAXINFO lpmmi:0012EEF4
<00232> 001F1732 R  WM_GETMINMAXINFO lpmmi:0012EEF4
<00233> 001F1732 R WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING
<00234> 001F1732 S WM_NCCALCSIZE fCalcValidRects:True lpncsp:0012F3D8
<00235> 001F1732 R WM_NCCALCSIZE fuValidRect:0000 lpncsp:0012F3D8
<00236> 001F1732 S WM_NCPAINT hrgn:00000001
<00237> 001F1732 R WM_NCPAINT
<00238> 001F1732 S WM_ERASEBKGND hdc:09012308
<00239> 001F1732 R WM_ERASEBKGND fErased:True
<00240> 001F1732 S WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED lpwp:0012F404
<00241> 001F1732 S  WM_MOVE xPos:950 yPos:404
<00242> 001F1732 R  WM_MOVE
<00243> 001F1732 S  WM_SIZE fwSizeType:SIZE_RESTORED nWidth:282 nHeight:79
<00244> 001F1732 R  WM_SIZE
<00245> 001F1732 S  WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING lpwp:0012F064
<00246> 001F1732 R  WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING
<00247> 001F1732 S  WM_NCCALCSIZE fCalcValidRects:True lpncsp:0012F038
<00248> 001F1732 R  WM_NCCALCSIZE fuValidRect:0000 lpncsp:0012F038
<00249> 001F1732 S  WM_NCPAINT hrgn:00000001
<00250> 001F1732 R  WM_NCPAINT
<00251> 001F1732 S  WM_ERASEBKGND hdc:16011DB5
<00252> 001F1732 R  WM_ERASEBKGND fErased:True
<00253> 001F1732 S  WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED lpwp:0012F064
<00254> 001F1732 R  WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED
<00255> 001F1732 R WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED
<00256> 001F1732 S WM_PAINT hdc:00000000
<00257> 001F1732 R WM_PAINT
<00258> 001F1732 P WM_MOUSEMOVE fwKeys:MK_LBUTTON xPos:-9 yPos:28
```

The indents in lines 241 to 254 were added by me to make it more obvious that those messages are nested. That is, they were sent by the WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED message in line 240.

Here is the associated WndProc (this is all from the default project created by Visual Studio 2005, except where marked to show code that I have added):

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    LRESULT lReturnValue = 0; //---added by me
    static int lcount = 0; //---added by me

    switch (message)
    {
    //---added by me from here vvvv
    case WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED:
        ++lcount;
        lReturnValue = DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        //--lcount;
        return lReturnValue;
    case WM_ERASEBKGND:
    case WM_NCPAINT:
        {
            wchar_t a[20];
            _itow(lcount, &a[0], 10);
            OutputDebugString(a);
            OutputDebugString(L"\n");
        }
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    //---added by me to here ^^^^
    case WM_COMMAND:
        wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
        wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
        // Parse the menu selections:
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case IDM_ABOUT:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        // TODO: Add any drawing code here...
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I run this, the VS output window has the following in it:

```
0
0
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
etc
```

If I uncomment the

```
//--lcount;
```

line I get:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
etc
```

I don't understand why? I would expect to get:

```
0
0
1
1
0
0
1
1
etc
```

where the 1's represent calls to WM_ERASEBKGND and WM_NCPAINT from inside WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED (as shown in the Spy++ output). There's obviously some fundamental misunderstanding on my part, and I can't figure it out! Any ideas/suggestions to try gratefully accepted...

If you agree with what I have stated as my expected behavior for this code I would also appreciate a comment to say so. That way I know I'm not looking at it completely wrong. :)

Edit: I think Spy++ is lying! I added an OutputDebugString call at the top of WndProc to output the number of *every* msg received by the window and got:

```
[WM_MOUSEMOVE] // not received
WM_SIZING              
WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING   
 WM_GETMINMAXINFO      
WM_NCCALCSIZE          
WM_NCPAINT             
WM_ERASEBKGND          
WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED    
 WM_MOVE               
 WM_SIZE               
 [WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING] // not received
 WM_NCCALCSIZE         
 WM_NCPAINT            
 WM_ERASEBKGND         
 [WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED] // not received
WM_PAINT               
[WM_MOUSEMOVE] // not received
```

where the 'not received' lines are msgs Spy++ says the window gets but they never show up in WndProc! Moreover, if I put a breakpoint at the very beggining of WndProc, and another on the DefWindowProc call in WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED, then step over the DefWindowProc call the breakpoint at the beggining of WndProc does not fire...meaning that *no* msg is received by the WndProc as a result of the DefWindowProc call in WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED. Unless someone can see something I'm missing, Spy++ does not accurately show the messages your window receives, but rather some mangled version of them, as I show above!

Comment: Move ++lcount before the switch statement.

Comment: OK, I tried that. But then lcount gets incremented for every message received by the window, so it gets bigger and bigger and bigger (occasionally getting decremented when a WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED msg is received). What was your idea?

Comment: I agree with you about the expected behavior, and I am as surprised as you with the result. As soon as I have a Windows machine at hand I'll try... BTW what did you do to emit the WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED message? Manually move the window?

Comment: Yes, I just dragged the left edge outwards.

Comment: Of course you'll have to decrement it before every return statement.

Comment: Hans, yes, but then all lcount is is a count of whether *any* msg is currently being processed, whereas it's purpose is to count if a *WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED* msg is currently being processed...

Comment: You could add another OutputDebugString at the end of WndProc, and `goto end;` instead of return, and see the Spy log as it is really.

Answer (score 0):

the reason that your experiencing this is because all the DefWindowProc() will do with WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED is add WM_SIZE and WM_MOVE events to the message queue [See msdn here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632652%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) so this code:

```
++lcount;
lReturnValue = DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
--lcount;
```

just increments lcount, adds a the WM_SIZE and WM_MOVE messages to the queue then decrements lcount. WM_NCPAINT wont get called between those two operations on lcount.

Hope that helps?

Comment: Not really, no. See my edit, and remember that I was going (I repeat *was* going) on what Spy++ was telling me. If you look at the Spy++ output at the very top of this thread, between line 240 (where WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED is sent) and line 255 (where WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED returns) there is supposed to be a whole slew of messages sent to the window (according to Spy++).

Comment: Iv been reading about, and still a bit puzzled by this. It looks like something is getting to the WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING and WM_MOUSEMOVE messages before you do, but I cant think what.  Have you tried writing an case for the WM_MOUSEMOVE event and seeing if you ever get to it?

Comment: I get WM_MOUSEMOVE if I'm moving the mouse over the window and doing nothing else, but I don't get WM_MOUSEMOVE whilst I'm dragging the edge of the window (I've no idea if I'm supposed to get it then too - only Spy++ says the window is getting it then too).

Comment: Bear with me 2minutes while I crack out the Petzold

Answer (score 0):

I've just duplicated your experiment and this is what I've got:

```
<00494> 000307A6 P WM_MOUSEMOVE fwKeys:MK_LBUTTON xPos:-4 yPos:173
<00495> 000307A6 S WM_SIZING fwSide:WMSZ_LEFT lprc:0012F71C
<00496> 000307A6 R WM_SIZING fProcessed:False
<00497> 000307A6 S WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING lpwp:0012F710
    <00498> 000307A6 S WM_GETMINMAXINFO lpmmi:0012F36C
    <00499> 000307A6 R WM_GETMINMAXINFO lpmmi:0012F36C
<00500> 000307A6 R WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING
<00501> 000307A6 S WM_NCCALCSIZE fCalcValidRects:True lpncsp:0012F6E4
<00502> 000307A6 R WM_NCCALCSIZE fuValidRect:0000 lpncsp:0012F6E4
<00503> 000307A6 S WM_NCPAINT hrgn:00000001
    <00504> 000307A6 S WM_GETTEXT cchTextMax:510 lpszText:0012EB68
    <00505> 000307A6 R WM_GETTEXT cchCopied:3 lpszText:0012EB68 ("F")
<00506> 000307A6 R WM_NCPAINT
<00507> 000307A6 S WM_ERASEBKGND hdc:A9010D6B
<00508> 000307A6 R WM_ERASEBKGND fErased:True
<00509> 000307A6 S WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED lpwp:0012F710
    <00510> 000307A6 S WM_MOVE xPos:141 yPos:218
    <00511> 000307A6 R WM_MOVE
    <00512> 000307A6 S WM_SIZE fwSizeType:SIZE_RESTORED nWidth:991 nHeight:664
    <00513> 000307A6 R WM_SIZE
<00514> 000307A6 R WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED
<00515> 000307A6 S WM_PAINT hdc:00000000
<00516> 000307A6 R WM_PAINT
<00517> 000307A6 P WM_MOUSEMOVE fwKeys:MK_LBUTTON xPos:-5 yPos:173
<00518> 000307A6 S WM_SIZING fwSide:WMSZ_LEFT lprc:0012F71C
<00519> 000307A6 R WM_SIZING fProcessed:False
<00520> 000307A6 S WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING lpwp:0012F710
    <00521> 000307A6 S WM_GETMINMAXINFO lpmmi:0012F36C
    <00522> 000307A6 R WM_GETMINMAXINFO lpmmi:0012F36C
<00523> 000307A6 R WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING
<00524> 000307A6 S WM_NCCALCSIZE fCalcValidRects:True lpncsp:0012F6E4
<00525> 000307A6 R WM_NCCALCSIZE fuValidRect:0000 lpncsp:0012F6E4
<00526> 000307A6 S WM_NCPAINT hrgn:00000001
    <00527> 000307A6 S WM_GETTEXT cchTextMax:510 lpszText:0012EB68
    <00528> 000307A6 R WM_GETTEXT cchCopied:3 lpszText:0012EB68 ("F")
<00529> 000307A6 R WM_NCPAINT
<00530> 000307A6 S WM_ERASEBKGND hdc:A9010D6B
<00531> 000307A6 R WM_ERASEBKGND fErased:True
<00532> 000307A6 S WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED lpwp:0012F710
    <00533> 000307A6 S WM_MOVE xPos:139 yPos:218
    <00534> 000307A6 R WM_MOVE
    <00535> 000307A6 S WM_SIZE fwSizeType:SIZE_RESTORED nWidth:993 nHeight:664
    <00536> 000307A6 R WM_SIZE
<00537> 000307A6 R WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED
<00538> 000307A6 S WM_PAINT hdc:00000000
<00539> 000307A6 R WM_PAINT
```

This is consistent with the MSDN documentation about WM_WINDOWSPOSCHANGED and WM_WINDOWSPOSCHANGING and moreover it is what we would expect.

So, or your Spy++ version is wrong or your Windows is doing nasty things.